# Reify generic class reflection given parameter class reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a generic class that I need to return complete type info for, and I have the class information for the generic parameter type. How might I upgrade the class information for the generic type parameter?

```java
public class MyClass<T> {
  public String key;
  public T value;

  Class<MyClass> getTypeInfo(Class<T> cls) {
    // How do I upgrade this with the reified type info in cls?
    return MyClass.class;
  }
}
```

Ultimately, I'm writing a [deserialization schema](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/util/serialization/DeserializationSchema.html) for Flink, and Need to return a reified class information in getProducedType as part of the interface. The class returned by the deserializer is a something like MyClass where I know the class information of T.

https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-reflection-class-gettypeparameters.html

EDIT: Given the lack of parameter information in Java Class, the Flink TypeInformation must be constructed directly, see below.

```
Types.POJO(
        (Class<MyClass<T> >) (new MyClass<T>()).getClass(),
        Map.ofEntries(
          entry("key", TypeInformation.of(String.class)),
          entry("value", TypeInformation.of(cls))
        ));
```

Comment: Could you provide examples of what you want to achieve/how you would want to use this? The problem is that due to type erasure there is no difference between `Class<MyClass<A>>` and `Class<MyClass<B>>` - it will always be `MyClass.class` (or  `Class<MyClass>`).

Comment: I know that because T is generic, its type info won't be included in MyClass.class, but I have T's type information already. So how do I go about making sure the parameter information for T in MyClass.class isn't just a stub?

Comment: Well, if you already have the type `Class<T>` then why don't you analyze that individually, e.g. check that it isn't an abstract class or interface etc.?

Comment: Additionally, I don't think `Class` has space for the information you're looking to store.  I believe you'd want to build a `ParameterizedType` in the method.

Comment: Interesting, so it sounds like the answer is just "not possible". Unfortunately, I'm not the one using getProducedType. It's unclear if/how that function is being used as part of the Flink API.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeParameters() It seems like Class does store that information in some way

Comment: @NedBingham: `getTypeParameters` stores information about the type _parameter_, not the current argument to it.  So in your example, it would be `T` with no bounds.

Comment: Had some time to look at this. Looks like there’s a static factory method for TypeInformation, which accepts a TypeHint. The documentation for that class shows how to specify one for generic types, and you can return that from getProducedType.

Comment: Unfortunately, TypeHint requires that I have the reified T to put into the template, which I don't :/

Comment: Got it working, my constructor was private o.O